# Cassandra : Delete the data without removing the table structure

Tags: cassandra, cql, truncate, cassandra-python-driver

I'm running some tests on cassandra, that need the data in the table to be removed after every run. So I wrote a script that TRUNCATES the data. My question is, does it leave the table unconfigured(removes all columns) after I TRUNCATE the table? I'm a cassandra beginner. Need some insights on this.

Answer (score 1):

**`TRUNCATE` command remove all data not schema**

```
TRUNCATE table_name;
```

> Removes all data from the specified table immediately and irreversibly, and removes all data from any materialized views derived from that table.

Source : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlTruncate.html